# Java не видит переменные окружения

Tags: java, ubuntu

Есть проект с maven. В нем есть такие строки:

```
System.getProperty("MY_VAL");
System.getenv("MY_VAL")
```

Я добавил эти пременные в файл ~/.bashrc и коммандой env в консоли убедился, что она там есть.

Но в проекте при дебаге нет их. Вышеприведенные комманды выдают null.

Что я не так сделал?

Comment: Попробуйте переменную окружения указать в `/etc/environment` Возможно, ваша приложение запускается не bash'ом.

Comment: вы установили property, а берете envirement переменные. `System.getProperty("MY_VAL")` должно помочь